# Any suggestion for my mobile app security

Tags: android

I am learning how to build android apps. I'm building my first app using PHP and Java, i'm passing the values from Java to PHP using parameters.

```
localhost/myfile.php?id=GET ID FROM JAVA EDITBOX&name=GET NAME FROM JAVA EDITBOX
```

I'm inserting and updating using this method.

But i'm afraid about my app security, how can i hide my links? I would like to insert some security technics to prevent a common user from having the access to my links, and insert random data into my database.

I'm sorry about that noob question, but i would like to read more about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can i hide my links

No way because APK file can be de-compiled

> I would like to insert some security technics to prevent a common user
>   from having the access to my links, and insert random data into my
>   database.

You are allowing Un-authenticated users to insert the records??? If you are doing this, you are doing it wrong (I think)

You should allow Authenticated Users to Insert/Delete/Update records and
Un-authenticated users can Load data only.

**Some Security Practices:**

1. Authentication (Login) / Authorization (Permission)
2. Don't trust any data sent from client --> Data Validation at Server side is required
3. Use Asymmetric encryption - Public/Private key

   - Encrypt your data at client side using Public key
   - Decrypt the data at Server side using Private key
4. Apply Digital Signature OR MAC (Message Authentication Code) to make sure your data is Integrity & Authentication
5. Https used